# Agregar mensaje de error en cada apartado del formulario

Tags: php, html, api

actualmente tengo un problema para mostrar los mensajes de error traídos de parte del servidor a mi formulario. este es mi formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en caso de que el usuario cometa un error en la información a registrar deberá de mostrar el error que tiene en cada respectivo lugar del formulario.

informacion que se obtiene por parte del servidor en un error

```
{
    "status":"error",
    "status_code":409,
    "message":"Validations failed, see validations for more details",
    "validations":{
        "name":"The name field is required.",
        "emailuser":"The field email user must be between 6 and 120 characters in length",
        "passworduser":"The password user field is required.",
        "confirmpass":"The Password Confirmation field is required."},
    "data":null
}
```

en el caso de un error en el campo por ejemplo name como podría mandar el error de validations en el campo name al formulario

```
<form id="registerForm">
      <h2>REGISTER</h2>
      <input type="text" placeholder="User" id="name"  name="name">
      <span>insertar mensaje error</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="emailuser"  name="emailuser">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="passworduser"  name="passworduser">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="confirmpass"  name="confirmpass">
      <input type="hidden" placeholder="" id="type"  name="type" value="Administrador">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Register">
</form>
```

es posible mandar una etiqueta span con el error de cada campo?

Comment: El envío del formulario lo haces por javascript via Ajax o directamente en el form de html?

Comment: Lo que planteas no tendría nada que ver con el servidor, sino con el cliente. Desde HTML5 puedes usar `setCustomValidity` para personalizar los mensajes de error de los campos marcados como `required` en un formulario, de modo que puedes implementar código Javascript **en el cliente** para mostrar cada mensaje determinando el input erróneo por su `id`. Revisa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5272433/5587982) y sus respuestas. La validación en el servidor es otra historia y tendrías que hacerlo verificando allí con `$_GET` o `$_POST` según el caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu idea es correcta, solo necesitas agregar ID a los contenedores para poder asignar el mensaje:

```js
// Esto es lo que recibes al procesar el formulario
let response = {
    "status":"error",
    "status_code":409,
    "message":"Validations failed, see validations for more details",
    "validations":{
        "name":"The name field is required.",
        "emailuser":"The field email user must be between 6 and 120 characters in length",
        "passworduser":"The password user field is required.",
        "confirmpass":"The Password Confirmation field is required."},
    "data":null
};

// Solo si hay error
if(response.status == 'error') {
    // Colocar mensaje en formulario
    document.querySelector('#message-error').innerText = response.message;
    // Recorrer validaciones por clave
    for(let key in response.validations) {
        // Asignar mensaje al span correspondiente
        document.querySelector(`#${key}-error`).innerText = response.validations[key];
    }
}
```

```css
input {
    display:block;
    margin-top:1em;
}
```

```html
<form id="registerForm">
      <span id="message-error"></span>
      <h2>REGISTER</h2>
      <input type="text" placeholder="User" id="name"  name="name" required>
      <span id="name-error"></span>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="emailuser"  name="emailuser" required>
      <span id="emailuser-error"></span>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="passworduser"  name="passworduser" required>
      <span id="passworduser-error"></span>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="confirmpass"  name="confirmpass" required>
      <span id="confirmpass-error"></span>
      <input type="hidden" placeholder="" id="type"  name="type" value="Administrador">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Register">
</form>
```

Como bien te dijeron en comentarios, es recomendable usar el atributo `required` en cada *input*, pero aún debes hacer las validaciones del lado del servidor.

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono, ya me marca los errores en cada respectivo campo, solo fue necesario la parte de document.queryselector y el id de los span.